# Webscraping Instagram follower count BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm just starting to learn how to web scrape using **BeautifulSoup** and want to write a simple program that will get the follower count for a given Instagram page. I currently have the following script (pulled from another Q&A thread):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user = "espn"
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ user
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
followers = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'description'})['content']
follower_count = followers.split('Followers')[0]
print(follower_count)

# 10.7m
```

The problem I am running into is I want to get a more precise number, which you can see when you hover the mouse over the follower count on the Instagram page (e.g., 10,770,816).

Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to do this with BeautifulSoup. I'd like to do this without the API since I am combining this with code to track other social media platforms. Any tips?

Comment: I would iterate through all the `a` tags that contains the text `"followers"`. Once found, extract the title value.

Comment: @Claudio error 404

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the API is the easiest way, but I also found a very hacky way to do it:

```
import requests

username = "espn"
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + username
r = requests.get(url).text

start = '"edge_followed_by":{"count":'
end = '},"followed_by_viewer"'
followers= r[r.find(start)+len(start):r.rfind(end)]

start = '"edge_follow":{"count":'
end = '},"follows_viewer"'
following= r[r.find(start)+len(start):r.rfind(end)]

print(followers, following)
```

If you look through the response requests gives, theres a line of Javascript that contains the real follower count:

...`edge_followed_by":{"count":10770969},"followed_by_viewer":{`...

So I just extracted the number by finding the substring before and after.

Answer (score 4):

Instagram always responds with JSON data, making it a usually cleaner option to obtain metadata from the JSON, rather than parsing the HTML response with BeautifulSoup. Given that using BeatifulSoup is not a constraint, there are at least two clean options to get the follower count of an Instagram profile:

1. Obtain the profile page, search the JSON and parse it:

   ```
   import json
   import re
   import requests

   response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + PROFILE)
   json_match = re.search(r'window\._sharedData = (.*);</script>', response.text)
   profile_json = json.loads(json_match.group(1))['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']

   print(profile_json['edge_followed_by']['count'])
   ```

   Then, profile_json variable contains the profile's metadata, not only the follower count.
2. Use a library, leaving changes of Instagram's responses the upstream's problem. There is [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/), which can be used liked this:

   ```
   from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

   L = Instaloader()
   profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

   print(profile.followers)
   ```

   It also supports logging in, allowing to access private profiles as well.

   (disclaimer: I am authoring this tool)

Either way, you obtain a structure containing the profile's metadata, without needing to do strange things to the html response.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach ( the html source code has a json object that has all the data of the profile )

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   

req      = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36')
html     = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
response = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
jsonObject = response.select("body > script:nth-of-type(1)")[0].text.replace('window._sharedData =','').replace(';','')
data      = json.loads(jsonObject)
following = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count']
followed  = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']
posts     = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count']
username  = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][0]['node']['owner']['username']
```

Comment: what is myurl at line 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not really a general question on programming, you should find that the exact follower count is the `title` property of the `span` element containing the formatted follower count. You can query this property.

Answer (score 0):

The easist method to do this would be to dump the page html into a text editor and do a text search for the exact number of followers the person has. You can then zero into the element which contains the number.