# How can I quickly get the follower count for a large list of Instagram users?

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, instagram

I have the following program in python that reads in a list of 1390680 URLS of Instagram accounts and gets the follower count for each user. It utilizes the instaloader. Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile
# 1. Loading in the data
# Reading the data from the csv
data = pd.read_csv('IG_Audience.csv')
# Getting the profile urls
urls = data['Profile URL']

def getFollowerCount(PROFILE):
    # using the instaloader module to get follower counts from this programmer
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225334/webscraping-instagram-follower-count-beautifulsoup
    try:
        L = Instaloader()
        profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)
        print(PROFILE, 'has', profile.followers, 'followers')
        return(profile.followers)
    except Exception as exception :
        print(exception, False)
        return(0)

# Follower count List
followerCounts = []
# This loop will fetch the follower count for each user
for url in urls:
    # Getting the profile username from the URL by removing the instagram.com
    # portion and the backslash at the end of the url
    url_dirty = url.replace('https://www.instagram.com/', '')
    url_clean = url_dirty[:-1]
    followerCounts.append(getFollowerCount(url_clean))

# Converting the list to a series, adding it to the dataframe, and writing it to
# a csv
data['Follower Count'] = pd.Series(followerCounts)
data.to_csv('IG_Audience.csv')
```

The main issue I have with this is that it is taking a very long time to read through the entire list. It took 14 hours just to get the follower counts for 3035 users. Is there any way to speed up this process?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: Sometimes I will get this error message: JSON Query to (some username)/feed/: 429 Too Many Requests: redirected to login [retrying; skip with ^C]
HTTP error code 429 was returned because too many queries occurred in
the last time. Please do not use Instagram in your browser or run
multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel.
The request will be retried in 666 seconds, at 17:58.

Comment: However, after the elapsed time it will resume

Comment: You're making a new Instaloader in each loop. Maybe just make one outside the loop and call it?

Comment: Is there a query-rate limit? Are you adhering to it? Is the periodic 666 second delay the main thing you are trying to mitigate? did you read [https://instaloader.github.io/troubleshooting.html#too-many-requests](https://instaloader.github.io/troubleshooting.html#too-many-requests)

Comment: @wwii zenalc's fix helped improve the speed slightly and got rid of the too many requests error. My code now runs at approximately 30 accounts scraped per minute, but this too is still pretty slow. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Would removing the print statements make it faster? I mainly included them just so I could keep track of how many accounts have been completed so far

Comment: You could try to *parallelize* the *scrape* - There is a [decent example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) in the concurrent.futures documentation - but I think there was a caveat in the instaloader docs about running in parallel. . As is your question is a little too broad.

Answer (score -1):

First I wanna say I'm sorry for being VERY late but hopefully this can help someone in the future. I'm having a similar issue and I believe I found out why, when you get the followers you instaloader doesn't just go to the profiles page and read the number but it gets the URL and profile ID for each account and can only get so many at a time, the best way I can think to get around this would be to make a request to the page and just read the follower count on their main page issue with this however is after I believe 9999 followers it will start saying "10k" or "10.1k" so you'll be off by 100 and just gets worse if the person has over a million because then its off by even more.