# Best way to find/get username of all the Instagram influencers in the world

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, data-mining

I want to find/get username of all the Instagram influencers in the world who have more than 10k followers.

I have an idea in mind, we can search for a hashtag on instagram and retrieve all the username that have posted to this specific tag. Then for every unique username we will check if they have follower > 10k.

Any suggestions to reach the goal please...

Comment: What have you tried? What did you found while doing research?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `selenium` , `BeautifulSoup` , `request` or you can just use their APIs for your work. I am not going towards APIs part you can find/get help from their official documentation for APIs things. So let's go for scraping.

Firstly use `selenium` to do login and search for `hashtag`. Now you got the result of `hashtag` search you can scrape `user ids` using `BeautifulSoup`, you got `user ids` also then you can do main web scraping things, go into the every users profile and check if there `followers` is more the `10,000` or not and then save or do what you need if `followers` is more then `10,000` or if not then scrape another user profile.  I am not going to write any code, do you your own research and write a code for yourself. I am going to share some links that may help you to solve you problem.

From [this](https://medium.com/@srujana.rao2/scraping-instagram-with-python-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-8b72c186a058) article, you can do hashtag search in Instagram using `selenium` and get user tags. Now you have to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` for getting followers count. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225334/webscraping-instagram-follower-count-beautifulsoup) may help you for this problem. If you found speeding problem while going through users profile the you can use `threading` and `multiprocessing` for that. But firstly do all other steps and only go to threading and other steps because writing code for webscraping is bit tricky and doing threading is much easier than webscraping.

I have answered this as of your idea,

> I want to find/get username of all the Instagram influencers in the world who have more than 10k followers

But doing this things is very much hard then you can think of, there could be tens of thousands of users who has `10,000` followers  and that is you want to find `1M+` followers user name then also it is very hard thing. You can just do scraping from some website where there is list of top Instagram followers. It will make your task easier.

Don't forget to mark this as answer if this helps with solve your problem.

Comment: I know all of this. I am looking for other ways to do it my brother. I guess  total 100M influencers or so.

Comment: Oh! Okay! Then wait for other answers.

Comment: As I have told already, I had gave you details information and explanation based on your explanation and idea. But yeah! Doing that things is very hard I think and waiting for others is probably best option for you then