# how get the number follower Instagram with Python

Tags: python, instagram-api

I need to find the number of followers of an account Instagram with python3
I know that Instagram has changed the political access .

I tried to download https://www.instagram.com/user/?__a=1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

# instagram URL
URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/user/?__a=1'

query = "selenium"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.google.com?q=' + query
res = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

response = json.loads(res.text)
print(response)
```

Nevertheless , i can't find the number of followers .

I create an account on developers.facebook.com . I have an API with ID and secret code. Nevertheless , I didn't look a good example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webscraping Instagram follower count BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225334/webscraping-instagram-follower-count-beautifulsoup)

Comment: This answer doesn't work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the Instagram account info by using the [facebook-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk) for python.
If your IG Account is connected via Facebook, you can get the info in this way:

```
session = FacebookSession(
config['app_id'],
config['app_secret'],
config['access_token'],
)
api = FacebookAdsApi(session)

fb_account = AdAccount("act_***") # Your FB account_id
ig_account = fb_account.get_connected_instagram_accounts(
                        fields=["followers_count"])
```

You can find the list of fields [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user).